# PHP Display image issue in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress

On this page http://www.cardiffchristmasmarket.com/visit/ i'm trying to get 4 images to display down the side - only 3 images display and when i upload the 4th to the page in WordPress it just removes it instantly. HELP!

PHP of the page below:

```
<div class="col span_1_of_4">


<div class="page_image">

    <?php if( get_field('image_1') ): ?>

        <a href="/find-us"><img src="<?php the_field('image_1'); ?>" /></a>

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<div class="page_image">

    <?php if( get_field('image_2') ): ?>

        <img src="<?php the_field('image_2'); ?>" />

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<div class="page_image">

    <?php if( get_field('image_3') ): ?>

        <img src="<?php the_field('image_3'); ?>" />

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>

<div class="page_image">

    <?php if( get_field('image_4') ): ?>

        <img src="<?php the_field('image_4'); ?>" />

    <?php endif; ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Please check the name "image_4" is match with the id in the custom field
or check the return type of the image in the custom field

Answer (score 0):

Check your wordpress settings, it might be set to display three images only. It may be page settings or widgets, theme settings.

Answer (score 0):

It Seams that you are using ACF (Advanced Custom Fields)

Check this URL for displaying correctly the Images : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/image/

```
    <?php 

$image = get_field('image');

if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help guys!

The issue lay in the Custom Fields - the field name for image 4 was missing '_'

THANKS!